# Certification authority and document signing (ADCS)

Tags: active-directory

I have a domain network with several devices inside and I want to use the digital signature of enterprise documents within this domain network.

I want to use this with Active Directory Certificate Service.

Is it possible to implement it at all? So that users do not manually exchange certificates, but do it through a domain CA? Are there any good guides on how to do this?

I looked at several guides, created a root CA, issued several certificates for users through it and tried to sign some documents with them in Adobe Reader, but when I check the signature, I get a notification that this is an UNKNOWN signature and is not trusted.

Answer (score 0):

When I found this, I was searching wether Active Direcory's Certificate Services (AD CS) can to begin with, simulate a CA domain or not.

But your concern seems to be more around "trust", hence no, if you create your own CA, then unless you find a way to somehow install your CA's root-cert on people's devices, **not** a single device will ever trust a custom CA, except if the device is broken and/or buggy.